# Can I withdraw money from my Roth IRA to pay last year's tuition?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, withdrawal, tuition

I just learned I can withdraw money from my Roth IRA to pay tuition fees for a graduate degree without the 10% penalty. Can this be done retroactively at all? Specifically, can I sell enough right now to reimburse myself for tuition payed last year?

Comment: You can withdraw contributions from Roth IRA at any time without any tax or penalty, regardless of what purpose you are using the money for. And contributions come out first in Roth IRA withdrawals. Have you already withdrawn all your contributions?

Comment: Just to check: Why do you want to do this? Are you in serious financial need? If not, leave the money there. Wrecking your retirement funding (*early* funding, which is worth far more than anything you contribute later in your career due to compounding) just because the law allows you to do so without directly penalizing you is short-sighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [IRS Publication 590-B](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b#en_US_2022_publink100090258), it doesn't seem so:

> ...if you paid expenses for higher education **during the year**, part (or all) of any distribution may not be subject to the 10% additional tax

This seem to imply that the expense and the distribution must be in the same year.